# Grails, Spring Security and Mongo

Tags: mongodb, grails, spring-security

I try to configure Grails 3.1.4 rest-api aplication. I'd like to use Mongo and Spring Security for authentication, but when I erase from application.yml h2 datasource and hibernate and try to run application I get a lot of exceptions like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceInterceptor':
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1b3bb287' of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate4.support.AggregatePersistenceContextInterceptor]
while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1b3bb287':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method:
public void org.grails.orm.hibernate4.support.AggregatePersistenceContextInterceptor.setHibernateDatastores(org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore[]); nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore]
found for dependency [array of org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore]:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please take a [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an overview of how SO works. Be so kind and reformate the stacktrace and formulate a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this behavior with Grails 3.1.7 if you just comment out the default H2 and cache part in application.yml. However, it disappears for me, if I comment out the following:

```
// compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
```

For reference, I'm using the following plugin versions for mongoDB and spring-security-core:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:5.0.6'
compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2"
runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
```

Cheers!